# how to count repeated values separated by commas from two separated tables in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, join

I can't figure out how to do this task. I have two tables with the same format and I have to count the top 10 most repeated actors considering the year taking the data from both tables.
the tables looks like this. and as you can see the column cast contains values separated by commas.

[image]

I did it in python, and it looks like this:

[(' Anupam Kher', 39),
(' Rupa Bhimani', 27),
(' Om Puri', 27),
('Shah Rukh Khan', 26),
(' Boman Irani', 25),
(' Paresh Rawal', 25),
(' Julie Tejwani', 24),
('Akshay Kumar', 23),
(' Jim Cummings', 23),
('Adam Sandler', 21)]

Comment: You should have a look on SPLIT_PART and use this function for both tables, then count the results and apply a HAVING clause or use LIMIT. I think you will be able to build a correct query. By the way, cast is no good column name since this is a SQL key word, so you need to quote the column name in queries. It would be better to rename this column.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I figured out how to do it (in my own way) because I have too little experience in sql

first of all I create a table with the needed information from the two tables:

```
create table multiple as
(select casting, release_year from public."Tabla_Disney"
union
select casting, release_year from public."Tabla_Netflix")
```

then I splitted the values from the column then i count them

```
SELECT count(casting) as my_count, casting
FROM (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(casting, ',')) AS casting
    FROM public.multiple where release_year = '2021') AS casting
GROUP BY casting
order by my_count desc
LIMIT 10
```

The result:

7   " Fortune Feimster"
6   " London Hughes"
6   "David Spade"
5   " Grey Griffin"
4   " Fred Tatasciore"
4   " Kari Wahlgren"
4   " Tress MacNeille"
4   " Wataru Takagi"
3   " Aditi Rao Hydari"
3   " Dee Bradley Baker"

Comment: I think you've done a good job to find the solution on your own (as I already assumed in my comment above) and this will help you much more than someone just give you the query. The creation of an own table is not the only way, but I think there is nothing wrong to do it that way. Just a small hint: You could use union all instead of union, this will improve the execution time.

Comment: @JonasMetzler thx, I apprecciate your concern, I found another solution using a Join method. too.